# How to efficiently download whole directories from an azure data lake via the Python API?

Tags: azure, azure-data-lake

I have some data (several GB) in an azure data lake spread across multiple files of 2MB each. I would like to write a download script to fetch the full directory. So far I have been trying an approach similar to the [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/data-lake-storage-directory-file-acl-python#download-from-a-directory)

```
azure_service_client = DataLakeServiceClient.from_connection_string(azure_connection_string)
file_system_client = service_client.get_file_system_client(file_system="my-file-system")
parent_directory_client = file_system_client.get_directory_client("my-directory")

for file_path in azure_all_files:
    file_client = parent_directory_client.get_file_client(file_path)
    download = file_client.download_file()
    downloaded_bytes = download.readall()

    target_path = os.path.join(self.local_data_directory, file_path)
    with open(target_path, 'wb') as file:
        file.write(downloaded_bytes)
```

But this is extremely slow, about 1 minute per file, i.e. 30 seconds per MB (no, it is not my internet connection). What am I missing here? Is the Python API just not the appropriate tool? Are some of the calls above redundant? Could it be parallelized?

Comment: This isn't really an answer but I've done a similar thing for Azure Databricks but not data lake. Instead of using the API directly yourself, you should install the azure-datalake-store library. There's an "ADLDownloader" method that lets you chunk large files and download full directories - https://github.com/Azure/azure-data-lake-store-python#performant-up-down-loading

Comment: Hi @Jonn Dove, Kindly let me know if you need more information. : )

Answer (score 3):

I think we can use [ADLDownloader Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-datalake-store/azure.datalake.store.multithread.adldownloader?view=azure-python) in azure.datalake.store package to increase download rate. It launches multiple threads for efficient downloading, with chunksize assigned to each. The remote path can be a single file, a directory of files or a glob pattern. The example is [here](https://pypi.org/project/azure-datalake-store/).

The pseudo code is as follows:

```py
tenant_id = '<your Azure AD tenant id>'
username = '<your username in AAD>'
password = '<your password>'
store_name = '<your ADL name>'
token = lib.auth(tenant_id, username, password)
# Or you can register an app to get client_id and client_secret to get token
# If you want to apply this code in your application, I recommended to do the authentication by client
# client_id = '<client id of your app registered in Azure AD, like xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxx'
# client_secret = '<your client secret>'
# token = lib.auth(tenant_id, client_id=client_id, client_secret=client_secret)
adl = core.AzureDLFileSystem(token, store_name=store_name)
ADLDownloader(adl, file_path, target_path, nthreads=None, chunksize=268435456, buffersize=4194304,blocksize=4194304,client=None, run=True, overwrite=False, verbose=False, progress_callback=None, timeout=0)
```

Comment: Hi @Jonn Dove, If my answer is helpful for you, please accept(mark) it as answer. This can be beneficial to other community members. Very thanks!

Comment: I think ADLDownloader is only available for Datalake Gen1. And for Gen2 they use completely different library and APIs.